# exoplayer setPlayWhenReady() not working why?

Tags: android, service, exoplayer

I use this [ExoPlayer demo](https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample) for playing audio streaming.
I modified code for playing audio with notification.
for this I put Exoplayer code in service class, but pause method not working don't know what happens but `setPlayWhenReady(false)` not working in service. Check this modified [source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVL68pDY5gFNZVunmOKoV5Uw9U18pZ6R/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

That's because every time you setPlayWhenReady(false) , the `onPlayerStateChanged` method of ExoPlayer Listener Called and you are setting `setPlayWhenReady(true)` in the listener. 
So that's what you need to do :
1. define a field in your service :

```
boolean isPreparing;
```

2. set `isPreparing = true` before initializing the ExoPlayer :

```
isPreparing = true;
player.prepare(...);
```

3. in the `onPlayerStateChanged` method of ExoPlayer Listener :

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
  if(isPreparing && playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY){
     // do whatever you want
     isPreparing = false;
  }
}
```

And that's it.